# Firebase rule get target user uid

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm writing a Firebase rule to allow user a to access user b's 'Test' property:

```
"Test": {
    ".read":"root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('Test').child('subtest').val().contains('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMdv3wQRjIs2')",
}
```

Just figured out that the rule checks on the requestor (user a) not the target user b (could be wrong :) ).

Is there any way to write a rule to represent the target user's uid like 'auth.uid' for the requestor?

Or anything could be done at the target user level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking to do?

```
"$target":{
        ".write": "root.child('path').val() == 'Value'"
      }
```

or

```
"Users": { //Path to where you store your users (case sensitive)
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
```

EDIT: OP found the solution using `".read": "data.child('allowed').val() == auth.uid",`

Comment: Thanks Torewin, please correct me if i'm wrong. As all users will share the same tree of rules in Firebase, if User A is requesting to access $uid of User B, and because Firebase rule will check the permission at User A's $uid level (auth.uid is for User A), how could we check if User A is allowed to access $uid of User B?

Comment: Or to put it in this way, since we're not able to add uid in the rules directly, how could we represent User B's uid using Firebase rules? So when let's say, there's another properties for User A that has User B's uid listed, when User A is trying to access User B's uid, how the rule could reflect User B's uid (or a new User C's uid) dynamically?

Comment: Do you want userA to access userB?

Comment: yes, that's correct. And because Firebase will check the rule at User A's side only, we could use auth.uid for User A, the requestor, but not sure how to represent the uid of User B in rules, guess it's not possible to add 10 users' uid in one rule...

Comment: It'll be much easier if the rule is performing the check at User B's side when User A is requesting access, so we could check if "auth.uid" is allowed or not. But it is checking at User A's side, is there anything Firebase could do to get "target.uid" for the requestor?

Comment: I do not believe you are able to have userA ‘know’ UserB’s uid. You can use a variable if you KNOW it but if it’s dynamic the whole point of these rules is for others to not find out. It’s a very difficult and confusing process.

Comment: figured that out, this is what i'm looking for: ".read": "data.child('allowed').val() == auth.uid", 'data' is for the path we're requesting and 'auth.uid' is for the requestor. thanks for the discussion!

Comment: I'll edit the answer to reflect what solved your question so people don't have to read comments.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the user's UID:

```
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
```

Comment: Thanks Mirza, but this is the code to get the current user/requestor's uid rather than the target user. and i'd like to write the rule in Firebase to get the target user's uid using something like '$target', just not sure what should be the exact parameter/code